# Binding element WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have this code.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="VideoControl" Width="Auto" Height ="{Binding altezza}"
   Source="intro.avi" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop">
</MediaElement>
```

In the `.cs` file I have this method

```
public int altezza{
   get { return 150; }
}
```

But it's not called from WPF element.

How I can fix it?

Thanks you for your reply

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set DataContext in XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192588/set-datacontext-in-xaml)

Comment: learning MVVM might help

Answer (score 2):

You must set the Datacontext to your Codebehind file:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Comment: While correct for the OP question/code, the data context should be a view model class, not the codebehind in MVVM.

Comment: I totally agree, @LordTakkera